# Can't left join a second table

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to left join a second table but it doesn't show up. It just gives me all users instead of all users along with the FinishedExams.

This is the method in my repository:

```
public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FinishedExam f ON u.id = f.user")
    List<User> getAllWithExams();
}
```

In my FinishedExamController:

```
@Autowired
private IFinishedExamRepository finishedExamRepository;

@Autowired
private IUserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping("/allUsersWithExams")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
public Iterable<User> getAllUsersWithTheirExams()
{
    return userRepository.getAllWithExams();
}
```

My User model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    public Role role;

    public String getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(String studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "student_number", nullable = true)
    private String studentNumber;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = true)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = true)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    private FinishedExam finishedExam;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = true)
    private String password;


    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "event_users",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
        updatedAt = createdAt;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role.getName();
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Finished exams model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "finished_exams")
public class FinishedExam implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id")
    private Exam exam;

    @Column(name = "finishedExam", nullable = false)
    private String finishedExam;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
        updatedAt = createdAt;
    }


    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Exam getExam() {
        return exam;
    }

    public void setExam(Exam exam) {
        this.exam = exam;
    }

    public String getFinishedExam() {
        return finishedExam;
    }

    public void setFinishedExam(String finishedExam) {
        this.finishedExam = finishedExam;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

I can put whatever I want in the ON clause but nothing changes.

Comment: Show the User class, you have to provide a path to join

Comment: I included my User model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a path from your entity to target entity to join:

Replace the query

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FinishedExam f ON u.id = f.user")
```

with

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.finishedExam f ON u.id = f.user.id")
```

Comment: It still gives me the same result. However if I put `u, f` in the SELECT clause it does return the exams along with it to me. The problem is it returns this `[{User: {User, Exams}}]` instead of `[{User, Exams}]`. What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Share me the Exams entity, you're referencing the wrong `where` condition

Comment: I've added the exams entity as well

Comment: Try my edited answer. But by the way, you did a left join with no condition on `User` class, it will still return all user no matter what. Do you want an inner join?

Comment: I need all users, with their finishedExam wether they have it or don't have it. I tried your query but it still gives the same result.

Comment: If you just wan to do that, just use getter method of your `User` entities: `user.getFinishedExam()` because your entities are mapped

Comment: Apologies for my stupidity I just defined the getFinishedExam() method but where am I supposed to use this? in the controller instead of findAll()?

Comment: Yes, do that. It's already mapped and fetched (via FetchType.EAGER)

Comment: But I can't access `getFinishedExam()` through the IUserRepository. Which is an extension from CrudRepository.

Comment: Dude. You must learn the basic things first before diving to the coding without any knowledge. In this case you do `return userRepository.getAllWithExams();`. Your `finishedExam` is also fetched and loaded in your users list. If you want to access `finishedExam` of a user, use `getter` method.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention it but I just need it to be added to the API when I access `/allUsersWithExams` along with the users. It's on EAGER mode so it should just show up right? Sorry I think I'm not quite following you

Comment: Yes. You don't event need a custom method. Just return `userRepository.findAll()` give you everything you need

Comment: Yea but it doesn't. It just gives me all users that's the problem

Comment: use the `findAll()` method

Comment: Yes I am. `/user/all` is using userRepository.findAll() but it doesn't contain the finishedExams table

Comment: After generating the getter and setter, jsonignoring the conflicting columns, and restarting the application it started to work thanks. Been a long day and everything started to look confusing.

Answer (score 1):

> I can put whatever I want in the ON clause but nothing changes.

Of course nothing changes.  You are performing a left join across a 1:1 relationship, selecting (only) the left entity, and not placing any filter criteria on that entity.  The join criteria (and indeed the join itself) don't matter: your query is equivalent to `SELECT u FROM User u`.

Did you perhaps mean to perform an inner join instead?

Comment: I need all users, with their finishedExam wether they have it or don't have it.

Comment: Since `User.finishedExam` is a mapped relationship, you don't need to perform an explicit join to get the exam data.  Just select all the `User`s and navigate the relationship normally.  Since you've declared the relationship with `FetchType.EAGER`, you don't even have to worry about entity detachment prior to such navigation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you mean I should do `userRepository.findAll();`, that just gives me all users without their exams. They are related however.

Comment: @SinanSamet, having retrieved the `User` entities, you should be able to simply invoke `user.getFinishedExam()` to retrieve the related `FinishedExam` entity, if any.  Of course, it would help if you actually *provided* such a getter (and a setter, too).  It's unclear why you declare the property but no accessors for it.

Comment: I have added the getter to the User model but like I said on the other answer using userRepository.findAll() only returns the users to me but not their finishedExams table.